# Can't connect to MySQL server (2006 Error)

Tags: php, mysql

so I'm recently using MySQL but a really weird thing is happening..

I hope I can find a solution here!

```
<?php
$servername = "theServername";
$username = "theUsername";
$password = "thePassword";
$dbname = "theDatabaseName";
$conn = new mysqli($servername,$username,$password,$dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("MySQL connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    echo "Couldn't connect.";
} 
else {
  echo "It connected.";
}
?>
```

and it keeps showing me

> Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): MySQL server has gone away in
>   C:\Users\Star1\PhpstormProjects\something\database.php on line 10
>
> Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): Error while reading greeting packet.
>   PID=7520 in C:\Users\Star1\PhpstormProjects\something\database.php on
>   line 10
>
> Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/2006): MySQL server has gone away in
>   C:\Users\Star1\PhpstormProjects\something\database.php on line 10
>   MySQL connection failed: MySQL server has gone away

and the 10th line for me is the `$dbname` which is the last parameter of `new mysqli` class.

NOTE: I put the right information inside the string quotes but this is just an example.

Comment: what is in line 10??

Comment: It's $dbname); which it's the database name

Comment: `$conn = new mysqli('$servername','$username','$password','$dbname');` change this and see

Comment: I have written the right information, but the code above was just an example. It still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

`$con = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password,$dbname);`

[More Details About- Mysql Server has gone away](http://piwik.org/faq/troubleshooting/faq_183/)

Comment: It still doesn't work, but the page you mentioned... where do I find my.cfg in the phpMyAdmin?

Answer (score 0):

```
$servername = "theServername";
$username = "theUsername";
$password = "thePassword";
$dbname = "theDatabaseName";
@$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
   die("MySQL connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
   echo "Couldn't connect.";
} else {
   echo "It connected.";
}
```

Comment: It throws just one error now, which is `MySQL connection failed: MySQL server has gone away` only...

Comment: Your mysql configuration file is likely to have problems, Can you show your mysql configuration information?

Comment: Where can I find it in phpMyAdmin?